# Getting more than one library with package name 'com.facebook'

Tags: android, facebook

I am doing Facebook Integration and got the following error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.facebook'
You can temporarily disable this error with`android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0`
```

You can check my build.gradle file is as follows,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.zaptech.latestfacebookintegration"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

Whats the problem is ? Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove

```
compile project(':facebook')
```

from build.gradle